# issue in order clause and limit in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sql-order-by

I am triggering this query

```
p "my query starts here..."
@relevant_customers_for_total_spent = Customer.order("total_amount DESC").where('id IN (?)',@customers_ids).limit(relevant_customers_count_for_total_spent)

 p " -------  "
 p relevant_customers_count_for_total_spent  # output is: 1139
 p @relevant_customers_for_total_spent.count # output is: 2888
 p " -------  "
```

More over log is saying the actual query fired is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `customers` WHERE (id IN (2,3,4,5,6,75,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,75,296,297,298,2889)) LIMIT 1139
```

**So the questions are:**

1. Why there is no order clause in the actual query?
2. Why @relevant_customers_for_total_spent.count is greater than relevant_customers_count_for_total_spent. It should be equals to or less than.

**Update -1 **

I got the second issue:

```
@relevant_customers_for_total_spent.length
```

is the right way to count the number of elements.

**Update - 2**

I have some customer ids in an array something like [2,3,4,5,6,75,56,57,58,59,60,61,62]. I have a attribute ie total_amount in Customer model. I want to rearrage all the customers ids in the order of total_amount (DESC). I have a another factor which specifies limit ie how many number of customers i need from that list. Some thing like if its 5. So I need top 5 customers from that araay based upon total_amount.

Comment: I believe you might br doing incorrect querying. Can you please explain the idea behind the query?

Comment: `where('id IN (?)',@customers_ids)` -- what an ugly construction! Use `where(id: @customers_ids)`. Rails will make `IN` for you if you're passing an array. In case of single value it'll make `=` clause. Passing relation (like `Model.select(:id)`) will give you nested SQL query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is: ARel is smart enough to generate a `count` query without `order` clause.

Just think of it: `#count` relation returns `select count(*) ...` SQL query, which, in turn, returns a single number - why would you need anything ordered here?

No wonder `#length` returns the correct number. That's because a relation object, on which `#length` is being called, not knowing how to respond to the call, triggers itself to return a result from DB, which is generally an instance of array, and then delegates the call down to it. Thus, calling `#length` on an instance of array returns expected number of elements.

**Update**

```
ids = [1,2,3,4,5]

Customer.where(id: ids).order('total_amount DESC').limit(5)
```

Comment: Just imagine i have customers ids in an array. Now I want to order them total_amount DESC. How will i do that..

Comment: Can you please update the question with a little bit more specific info on what are you trying to accomplish?