# Sort data in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

Association is like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :products
has_many :ratings
```

I want to sort products according to user ratings.
Let suppose I want to sort all those product whose ratings is greater than 4.
I cant find any way to do that.

I do something like

```
User.joins(:ratings).where("ratings.rate > ?", 4).includes(:ratings)
```

From that I get all user whose ratings is greater than 4 but how join with product and sort them?

Comment: Hey Usman, you should just accept one as a solution, to let other people know that you found your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User.joins(:ratings).where("ratings.rate > ?", 4).order('ratings DESC')`

I am not sure what `includes(:ratings)` doing at the last.
Should just use something like this and it should probably work:

`User.includes(:ratings).where("ratings.rate > ?", 4).order('ratings DESC')`

Reference: [issue in order clause and limit in active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597135/issue-in-order-clause-and-limit-in-active-record)

Answer (score 1):

```
User.joins(:ratings).where("ratings.rate > ?", 4).order('ratings.rate')
```

And if you want to find associated products then this should work:

```
Product.joins(user: :ratings).where("ratings.rate > ?", 4).order('ratings.rate')
```